# Writing to file using c and c++

Tags: c++, c

When I try to write the file using C; `fwrite` which accepts `void` type as data, it is not interpreted by text editor.

```
struct index
{
   index(int _x, int _y):x(_x), y(_y){}
   int x, y;
}

index i(4, 7);

FILE *stream;
fopen_s(&stream, "C:\\File.txt", "wb");
fwrite(&i, sizeof(index), 1, stream);
```

but when I try with C++; ofstream `write` in binary mode, it is readable. why doesn't it come up same as written using `fwrite`?

Comment: Sounds like you used `fwrite` incorrectly. Can you post some code?

Comment: What about your C++ code? What are you doing with ofstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to write binary data using a stream in C++:

```
struct C {
    int a, b;
} c;

#include <fstream>
int main() {

    std::ofstream f("foo.txt",std::ios::binary);
    f.write((const char*)&c, sizeof c);
}
```

This shall save the object in the same way as `fwrite` would. If it doesn't for you, please post your code with streams - we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, that explains why you have received the text output. If you want raw binary output, you know what to do now.

Comment: I wrote two files using C and C++ file stream in raw binary mode, but how come a file written using C is 90% larger in size than one I wrote using C++?

Comment: Check the stream example that I presented, it shall write exactly 8 bytes to the file. Indeed it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

C++'s ofstream stream insertion only does text.  The difference between opening a iostream in binary vs text mode is weather or not end of line character conversion happens.  If you want to write a binary format where a 32 bit int takes exactly 32 bits use the c functions in c++.

Edit on why fwrite may be the better choice:

Ostream's write method is more or less a clone of fwrite(except it is a little less useful since it only takes a byte array and length instead of fwrite's 4 params) but by sticking to fwrite there is no way to accidentally use stream insertion in one place and write in another.  More less it is a safety mechanism.  While you gain that margin of safety you loose a little flexibility, you can no longer make a iostream derivative that compresses output with out changing any file writing code.

Comment: Untrue, C++ stream objects are perfectly suitable for binary data too... One reason to prefer them over C alternatives is safety connected to having the file closed in the object's destructor.

Comment: @Kos capable true but fwrite provides the better interface.